# Change Permalink Structure for Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have a custom taxonomy called `colors`, which contains the terms  *Red*, *Blue*, *Yellow* etc.

Each post has a term of the taxonomy colors linked to it.
The default permalink structure for posts is `/%category%/%post-name%/`

i.e. posts are displayed at - `www.example.com/category-term/post-name`

I want to change the permalink structure such that the posts are displayed at
`www.example.com/taxonomy-term/post-name`
 i.e. `www.example.com/yellow/post-name`  -  for a post that has the term *Yellow* of the custom taxonomy linked to it.

Please suggest any method to do this..?